# Bind Hyperlink inside Server side code with another DataGrid's Column Value

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, bind

I'm Trying to Bind a Hyperlink Control " server side " to another Column's Value when Selected Index changed

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkID" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%# "WebPage.aspx?" & DataGridName.Items[DataGridName.SelectedIndex].Cells[8].Text]  %>'
                                     Visible="false">HyperLink Text</asp:HyperLink>
```

Is there a problem using `DataGridName.Items[DataGridName.SelectedIndex].Cells[8].Text]` 
while binding ?
I'm just trying to get the selected index to get its corresponding another column's value

Answer (score 0):

You try with `ItemCommand event` of your DataGrid.

In the code behind of `ItemCommand`

```
void ItemsGrid_Command(Object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
 HyperLinkID.NavigateUrl = "WebPage.aspx" &  e.Item.Cells[8].Text
}
```

Aspx Code

```
 <asp:DataGrid id="ItemsGrid"  ...
                    OnItemCommand="ItemsGrid_Command">
 <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonColumn 
                 HeaderText="Select item" 
                 ButtonType="LinkButton" 
                 Text="Select" 
                 CommandName="Select"/>  

  </Columns>
  </asp:DataGrid
```